# soup.find_all('div', {"class":"top_first_part clearfix"}) returns empty list when there are matches in webpage in real

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please find the code below which throws error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = "https://www.goibibo.com/flights/air-MAA-SIN-20190403--1-0-0-E-I/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url=url)
page_content = page.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content,"html.parser")
price = soup.find("svg",class_="recharts-surface")
print(price)
```

Comment: Please read and follow [mcve]. for everyone to understand your question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting and your expected output?

Comment: there is no svg in soup

Comment: if you save the html (page_content) in a file you will see there is no element svg, the website loads it in other request, its seems to be in an iframe

Answer (score 1):

it is worked for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import os
import time

current_dir=os.getcwd()
#download chromedriver for your os.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(current_dir+'/chromedriver1')
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/flights/air-MAA-SIN-20190403--1-0-0-E-I/")

inner_html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(inner_html,'html.parser')
price = soup.find("svg",class_="recharts-surface")
print(price)
```

[image: This is your output]

Answer (score 0):

You can get prices from script tag. You may need to fiddle with json parsing to get how you want

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

url = 'https://thor.goibibo.com/v2/thor/rest/flight/search/int?userid=asd&hash=2837423032023&application=fbs&flavour=v2&mime=html&script=y&actionData=[{%22query%22:%22air-MAA-SIN-20190403--1-0-0-E-0%22}]&slotfl=y1&nearbyfl=y1'

headers = {
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
s = soup.select_one("script[type='text/javascript']").text
data = re.search(r"window\.parent\.postMessage\((.*), '\*'", s ,flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
result = json.loads(data)

for item in result['o']:
    #print(item)
    print('ref ', item['id'])
    print('departure ', item['f'][0]['d'])
    print('arrival ', item['f'][0]['a'])
    try:
        print('price ', item['5'])
    except:
        print('price ', item['p1'])
```