# parsing a bit of HTML code with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some data on a specific website, I have located where the data i need is precisely but when I inspect it in chrome i see the data i need, the time, which when inspecting goes something like this on chrome:

```
<span data-push="clock">Half Time 34:11</span>
```

However when i locate to this specific text in python the time is nowhere to be seen (i suspect its hidden) (see second image attached), this data is obviously continuously updating, is there a way to find this data in python? This is what is returned in my code:

```
<span data-push="clock"></span>
```

The main problem is that im not sure if this data is being hidden for me or i am doing something incorrect in the parsing. Since i have located the correct line of code im not sure its the latter.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Perhaps, the url to which this html was fetched would be helpful.

Comment: The URL is changes every 90 minutes (since im attempting to derive stats from betting sites) i have successfully written a code to extract every url of a game in play and then i reparse depending on that output.

Answer (score 1):

If the time is placed using javascript you can not get that with using bs4 and python only, you have to use [selemium webdriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) -> which opens the webpage in browser-> capture source -> then use bs4 to get your desired text from the webpage source.

Comment: I have done exactly that, but the html code i extracted for some reason does not included the data i require (as i have shown in the two bits of code above), maybe its hidden from me somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, use .text method to extarct only text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base="""<span data-push="clock">Half Time 34:11</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(base,"html.parser")
data=soup.find('span').text
print(data)
```

Comment: Yes the problem is the code i parsed doesnt show me this text, it only appears on the inspected code on chrome.

Comment: which module you are using to fetch data requests , urllib or selenium

Comment: using urllib2 .

Comment: try with selenium web driver
check this solution ="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491089/soup-find-alldiv-classtop-first-part-clearfix-returns-empty-list-whe/55491410#55491410"

Comment: Just selenium instead of urllib but unfortunately no luck, the information i require still doesnt show up on my end but shows up on the inspection of the web page

Comment: might be your are selecting the wrong span, try to select by class or id of its parent element then find span

Comment: I tried to select some parent tags and found the span i wanted, i am in the correct place because its the only piece of html code like it in the entire script but the data i need is still for some reason not being recorded (this is from a betting website so i assume they have some measures in place for me not to be able to attain such data)

Comment: Managed a workaround by inspecting hidden elements through selenium directly without beautiful soup. Thank you!